# WCF service code in window application

Tags: wcf

I am using C#.net application code.

I require to call service for Window Application and i am using below code to open service Host,

```
 using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(
                typeof(class1),
                new Uri[] { new Uri("net.pipe://localhost") })
                )
            {
}
```

& Then we have clinet Console application to connect to serviceHost.

Problem is,

When i create service/Client application Using Conslole Application both are working fine.
But if i call servide code form Window application to connect to console client it gives Error for Binding Error like("No End Point/Address found to test")

Can any one help me to run service from C# window application ?

Thanks

Comment: A service does not connect to a client.

Answer (score 3):

You have a *using* statement wrapped around your host.  Once it goes out of scope, it is closed.
Make the host a class member of your form.  I usually also open it in a separate thread.

Comment: hey thanks Khadaji, i got that its because of using statement